# Entity Framework 6 - Null value in nested query with select

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am facing a problem in EF6. When I execute the query `Select` it return the value. But when I add `Select` it returns null.

The code is here:

The (W) is not null here...

```
        var list = db.X.Include("Y").Include("Z.W")
            .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
            .Skip(pageSize * page)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
```

Here, The W value is null...

```
        var list = db.X.Include("Y").Include("Z.W")
            .Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Z})
            .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
            .Skip(pageSize * page)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
```

Please help :)

**UPDATE 1**

```
public class academy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
   [StringLength(255)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public  Owner owner { get; set; }

    public  List<location> Location { get; set; }           
}


public class location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public  academy Academy { get; set; }

    public  List<stadium> Stadiums { get; set; }

    public List<Administrators> Administrators { get; set; }

    public List<addition> Addition { get; set; }

    public List<Pricing> Pricing { get; set; }

    public List<time_frame> TimeFrames { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Details {
        get { return (City + " - " + Street); }
    }

}


public class Pricing
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double? PriceAfterOffer { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public location Location { get; set; }
    public players_capacity StadiumCapacity { get; set; }


}

public class players_capacity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Capacity { get; set; }

}


        var list = db.locations
            .Select(a => new { a.Id, a.City, a.Region, a.Street, a.Latitude, a.Longitude, a.Pricing, a.Academy })
            .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
            .Skip(pageSize * page)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
```

**The problem is on players_capacity always null**

Answer (score 2):

Any additional data specified by `Include` is ignored if the query changes "shape", in this case your additional `.Select` expression invalidates the previous `Include` terms so they are ignored. The same happens if you do a `GroupBy` or `GroupJoin`.

Fortunately the fix is simple: explicitly specify the `Y` and `Z.W` members in your projection:

```
var list = db.X
    .Select( x => new { x.Id, x.Z, x.Y, x.Z.W } )
    .OrderBy( p => p.Id )
    .Skip( () => pageSize * page )
    .Take( () => pageSize )
    .ToList();
```

([Note that I'm using the `Expression<>` overloads of `Skip` and `Take`, as those are better for use with EF](https://anthonychu.ca/post/entity-framework-parameterize-skip-take-queries-sql/)).

Comment: Z is an array, so I am unable to write Z.W :(

Comment: Then what was `Include("Z.W")` meant to do in your original example?

Comment: Z in an Object, but X has an array of Z.

Comment: Then `Include("Z.W")` wouldn't have worked as-intended, or it would load a large amount of data from your database inefficiently. BTW you should use the `Include(lambda)` version instead of the `Include(String)` method, as it offers compile-time safety verification.

Comment: Good idea, but what about avoiding the null? It still null.. `Include(a => X.Z)` is giving me IQueryable Object, so I can not go deeper on the class to access W.

Comment: @sa94 Can you update your question with your database schema and an example of the kind of results you want to see?

Comment: Updated.. **UPDATE 1**